# How can I deactivate the write-protection in an OpenOffice-document?

Tags: macos, mac, openoffice, write-protect

I activated document-protection for a document (Open Office on a Macbook, very recent download), and now I can't deactivate it. Though I should be the user who is allowed to read and write, I can't write on it anymore or rename the file. When looking back on the document information it displays no protection, which I could deactivate. Hum?

It's the first time I use Open Office: Actually I just wanted a password-protection for the file.

How hard can it be?

Comment: If you could be a bit more specific about how you activated the protection, that would help.  Did you protect the file using something on your Mac book, or inside Open Office?

Comment: This nonsense should not even be a feature. See "Libre" word in software title.

Answer (score 9):

- From the menu, select **Format -> Sections**

  [image]
- Select your section in the left pane and  uncheck **Write Protected**

  [image]
- Enter the password you used when prompted

  [image]
- Click the **Remove** button on the right side to get rid of the section

  [image]
- Click OK

  [image]

Comment: Thank you! I just recognized, that I protected the superordinate file! 
Problem solved.

Comment: I can not get `sections…` in the format menu, to not be greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

Tools → Options → LibreOffice Writer → Formatting Aids:  check box labelled "Ignore Protection"

[image: A screenshot of the dialog with the check box in LibreOffice version 5.1.6.2 on Ubuntu]

Comment: The question was asked 7 years ago, I am guessing that a lot of things have changed since then. Can you include a screenshot of the window where this setting is located? Also please include the version of LibreOffice your instruction is applicable to.

Comment: Odd, I see all of those options except for `Ignore protection`.  I also have "Spaces" as an option for "Insert".

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are quite old and did not work for me.
Therefore, I looked for a newer answer, and found one [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/92124/write-protected-content-cannot-be-changed-but-id-like-to/?answer=139771#post-id-139771).

The solution is to go to

> Tools > Options... > LibreOffice Writer > Compatibility,

and then to remove the tick mark from the " Protect form" line. For me, this is the third line from below.

Comment: I found that too - yet I need a way to preserve this setting. Each saving this hook get set again - which makes it "not nice" to send someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice 7.1.0.3 on a BigSur-M1-MacBook you have to remove the tick of ***"Enable Cursor"*** under "Protected Areas" (upper right corner) in Perferences / LibreOffice Writer / Formating Aids.

As you can see from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZrKf.png) I added, there is no option "ignore protection", but to remove the tick from "Enable Cursor" works.